# Clash of xcolor and colortbl over a longtable

Tags: color, longtable, colortbl

The `longtable` below produces the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\adl@@cr ...tempdima \xdef \adl@rowsL {\adl@rowsL 
                                                  (\adl@colsL /\number \adl@...
l.16         w
              hy? & {\_..V} & {\_..\'{\i}} & $\acute{\upsigma}$ & -ir & exam...

?
```

The error disappears if I remove the "table" option from `xcolor`, but I need that option independently, so that is a solution I cannot keep.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek} %nicer greek symbols
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{booktabs}           %Prettier
\usepackage{arydshln}           %With dotted lines  
\usepackage{longtable}          %Long
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{rccccc}
        \caption{\textit{Mid-to-high alternation in 3\textsuperscript{rd} conjugation verbs}} \label{spa-table} \\
        why? & {\_..V} & {\_..\'{\i}} & $\acute{\upsigma}$ & -ir & example \\ \hline \endhead
        1 & \textbf{i} & \textbf{i} & \textbf{i} & 118 & \textit{vivir} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}    2 & \textbf{i} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{i} & 73 & \textit{pedir} \\ \hline
        3 & \textbf{i} & \textbf{i} & \textbf{ie} & 4 & \textit{adquirir} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}    4 & \textbf{i} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{ie} & 68 & \textit{sentir} \\ \hline
        5 & \textbf{u} & \textbf{u} & \textbf{u} & 239 & \textit{fundir} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}    6 & \textbf{u} & \textbf{o} & \textbf{ue} & 5 & \textit{dormir} \\ \hline
        7 & \textbf{u} & \textbf{u} & \textbf{---} & 2 & \textit{balbucir} \\ \hline \hline
        1 & \textbf{e} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{e} & 10 & \textit{divergir} \\ \hline
        2 & \textbf{e} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{ie} & 4 & \textit{discernir} \\ \hline
        3 & \textbf{e} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{---} & 8 & \textit{agredir} \\ \hline
        4 & \textbf{o} & \textbf{o} & \textbf{o} & 9 & \textit{descolorir} \\ \hline
        5 & \textbf{o} & \textbf{o} & \textbf{ue} & 0 & \textit{--} \\ \hline
        6 & \textbf{o} & \textbf{o} & \textbf{---} & 3 & \textit{abolir} \\ \hline \hline
        1 & \textbf{a} & \textbf{*} & \textbf{a} & 52 & \textit{partir} \\ \hline
        2 & \textbf{a} & \textbf{*} & \textbf{---} & 5 & \textit{embair} \\ \hline \hline
        1 & \textbf{*} & \textbf{*} & \textbf{*} & 1 & \textit{ir} \\ \hline \hline
        &  & Total &  & 601 & \textit{} \\ \cline{3-5}
\end{longtable} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Removing the `\rowcolor` command does not change anything, nor does adding "table" to the document class option. The error also remains if I remove `colortbl`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: It is a bit unfair to complain about xcolor and longtable and colortbl when the error is from arydshln. Check the documentation of arydshln about the loading order (or avoid the package, it is difficult).

Comment: Really? How do you know? In the meantime, I need `arydshln` independently, so removing it is not an option. But I reordered the table-related packages and NOW IT WORKS! Thank you for saving me!

Comment: If you already load `xcolor` with the table option, you don't really need to load `colortbl` afterwards

Comment: also you have not shown the error message just one small fragment of it with some of the context line but not the actual error rmessage (which you should always show in a code block as line endings are vital to read tex errors)

Comment: never put `longtable` in a `center` environment.

Comment: I added the error message showing the error is `\adl@rowsL` is undefined, which you had omited from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved! The answer was in the order of packages invoked, so here is the corrected order in case someone encounters the same obstacle:

```
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}          
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{arydshln}           
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

Comment: By specifying the `table` option when loading `xcolor`, you are loading the `colortbl` package automatically. Hence, *de facto* you are loading `colortbl` *before* rather than after `longtable` -- contrary to the impression the code you posted creates.